# Android null pointer fragment components

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm new in android developpement and I'm trying to work with my fragment components (Edittext, button, ...) but I get a nullpointer exception .

here's my onCreate method code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        idCpt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idCapteurEditText);
        capBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CapteurBtn);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        idCpt.setText("exemple");

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

any idea please ?

Comment: I think your widget is exists on `fragment_activity` so put your code in Fragment class or put widgets on `activity_main_menu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using views from `fragment_main_menu.xml` you will get null because in your activity you are using `activity_main_menu`

So either use `idCpt` and  `capBtn` in `activity_main_menu` layout or in `onCreateView` of your fragment inflate the view

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
```

then use the view to find the EditText and button

```
 idCpt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.idCapteurEditText);
 capBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.CapteurBtn);
```

i.e.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
           EditText idCpt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.idCapteurEditText);
           Button capBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.CapteurBtn);
          return v;
    }
```